# Adding two class in an html table

Tags: css, class, html-table, tablesorter

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224820/responsive-table-on-two-or-more-table-with-different-table-header) article, I made a class (t1) so that the table is positioned properly on a mobile device. Like this:

```
/*
Label the data
*/
.t1 td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
.t1 td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Category A"; }
.t1 td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Category B"; }
.t1 td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Category C"; }

.t2 td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
.t2 td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Category X"; }
.t2 td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Category Y"; }
.t2 td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Category Z"; }
```

I also added a table sorter from [this](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) website and the sorter is working fine too. The sorter already has a class (tablesorter)

When I use the following, the table is positioned properly on mobile because of the **t1** class

```
<table id="table1" class="t1" width="100%" border="1" >
```

When I use the following, the table is getting sorted because of the **tablesorter** class

```
<table id="table1" class="tablesorter" width="100%" border="1" >
```

Now my question I can use only one class in table so either mobile positioning happens properly or the sorter. I want both to function. Is it possible to use two classes in the table? I read an article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812531/adding-multiple-classes-on-table-td-html-css) but i think it does not apply to my problem. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

t2 class is working fine because i havent put a sorter on it.

Thank you

EDIT: Its not duplicate as I saw some function written for multiple classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812531/adding-multiple-classes-on-table-td-html-css) so got confused. I got the solution now however, added a comment "when the table is viewed row-by-row on mobile device, the sort function does not work. It works on desktop though! Is there any way to get it worked on mobile device?"

Comment: identity is defined once, classes are created multiple times separated by a space

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can define multiple classes to an element by separating them with a white space.

```
<table id="table1" class="t1 tablesorter" width="100%" border="1" >
```

From [**MDN Global Attributes Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#class):

> **class**
>   This attribute is a space-separated list of the classes of the element.

Comment: phew! it was that simple!! Thanks... when the table is viewed row-by-row on mobile device, the sort function does not work. It works on desktop though! Is there any way to get it worked on mobile device?

Comment: @MumbaiCabinCrew, in order not to mix the subjects, I suggest you open another question here on SO with this specific issue, providing the code if possible. We'll be glad to help! :)